# jq compilation error for two maps - not replacing json value

Tags: json, jq

I am observing an error with the following data when using two jq maps within a shell script.

### test.json

```
[
  {
     "ParameterKey": "<ans1>",
     "ParameterValue": "<ans2>"
  }
]
```

My script is

```
cat test.json | \
jq 'map(if .ParameterKey == "<ans1>" then . + {"ParameterKey" : "input1" } else . end )' \
   'map(if .ParameterValue == "<ans2>" then . + {"ParameterValue" : "input2" } else . end)' \ 
> result.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the precise error isn't given, running the command generates

```
jq: error: Could not open file map(if .ParameterValue == "<ans2>" 
then . + {"ParameterValue": "input2"} else . end): No such file or directory
```

The `No such file or directory` message indicates jq is trying to open a file 
named "**`map(if .ParameterValue == "<ans2>" then . + {"ParameterValue": "input2"} else . end)`**" which is happening because that string appears where jq expects the name of an input file.

To correct this you can combine the two filter strings into one string with `|` and pass `test.json` as the input file, e.g.

```
jq '
   map(if .ParameterKey == "<ans1>" then . + {"ParameterKey": "input1"} else . end)
 | map(if .ParameterValue == "<ans2>" then . + {"ParameterValue": "input2"} else . end)
' test.json > result.json
```

or keep your basic structure and add a second explicit jq invocation e.g.

```
cat test.json | \
jq 'map(if .ParameterKey == "<ans1>" then . + {"ParameterKey": "input1"} else . end)' | \
jq 'map(if .ParameterValue == "<ans2>" then . + {"ParameterValue": "input2"} else . end)' \
> result.json
```

In this particular case either will work but the first way is more efficient.  [Peak's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47385320/8379597) which uses only a single `map()` is better still.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions - one that is both simple and brief, and one that scales well. Notice that in both cases, `map` is only needed once.

#### Simple and brief

```
map( if .ParameterKey   == "<ans1>" then . + {"ParameterKey":   "input1"} else . end
   | if .ParameterValue == "<ans2>" then . + {"ParameterValue": "input2"} else . end)
```

#### With a helper function

```
def maybe_update($key; $old; $new):
  if .[$key] == $old then .[$key] = $new else . end;

map( maybe_update("ParameterKey";   "<ans1>"; "input1")
   | maybe_update("ParameterValue"; "<ans2>"; "input2") )
```